# Set location as if invisible pictures don't exist

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML and JavaScript. There are three pictures and three links. Clicking on one link shows one picture and hides the other two.

This works. However, I'd like it so that when a picture is shown, it is shown as if the other two pictures don't exist, instead of being pushed somewhere down the page. Is that possible?

HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img1')">show image1</a>
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img2')">show image2</a>
    <a href="javascript:showImage('img3')">show image3</a>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
     <img id="img1" src="berlin.jpg" height="200px"/>
     <img id="img2" src="london.jpg" height="200px"/>
     <img id="img3" src="madrid.jpg" height="200px"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function showImage(id) {
    var images_id = new Array("img1", "img2", "img3");
    for (var i = 0; i < images_id.length; i++) {
        setImageVisible(images_id[i], false);
    }
    setImageVisible(id, true);
}

function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
```

Use this:

```
img.style.display = (visible ? '' : 'none');
```